# Masonry & jQuery content toggles (slideDown, show etc.)

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm building a blog where I want to only display the relevant images of each blog post in a nicely ordered grid using Masonry. When the user clicks on an image the blog text content will be revealed beneath the image (on the same page). For some reason the hidden content won't show up when I add the click function. I'm not that familiar with the on() event handler (required because of Masonry) and there might be something obvious that I'm missing. What happens is I see in the DOM that the  elements get display: block, yet they don't show up.

The HTML -

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
        <div id="posts" class="clearfix">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="post">
                <a class="view" href="#"><?php the_post_thumbnail(465, 999) ?></a>
                <div class="overlay">+</div>
                <article>
                    <a href="#" class="close">x</a>
                    <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
                    <hr>
                    <?php the_content() ?>
                    <span><?php the_date('Y/d/m') ?></span>
                </article>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif;  ?>
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The JavasScript -

```
var $container = $('#posts');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.post',
            columnWidth: 475,
            isAnimated: true
        });
    });

    $(document).on("click", "a.view", function(){
        if(!$(this).parent().find('article').is(':visible')){
            $(this).parent().find('article').slideDown(250);
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().find('article').slideUp(250);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on("mouseover", "a.view", function(){
      $(this).parent().find('.overlay').stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 250);
    });
    $(document).on("mouseout", "a.view", function(){
      $(this).parent().find('.overlay').stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 250);
    });
```

Comment: Do you have an Url where I can see the real thing, with css and all ? I tried your code with and without masonry and it works as I guess it should, so it might be the combination of masonry and your css causing it...

Comment: Yes - http://staffanestberg.com/lesmarket/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a look at your site, and I belive that your problem is that Masonry is calculating sizes and positions when you run .masonry() and set all elements to position:absolute and then when you expand the text it will be hidden by the item beneath...

So you need "update" the masonry() after expanding an item. I don't know the plugin that well, but maybee $('#posts').masonry('reload'); will do the trick :) !

Comment: I haven't figured on how to solve this problem yet, but your suggestion is the closest to a solution. Thanks for pointing out this important method in Masonry.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, but try with something like that with live() perhaps :

```
var $container = $('#posts');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.post',
        columnWidth: 475,
        isAnimated: true
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.view").live("click", function(){
            if(!$(this).parent().find('article').is(':visible')){
                $(this).parent().find('article').slideDown(250);
            }
            else {
                $(this).parent().find('article').slideUp(250);
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    $("a.view").live("mouseover", "a.view", function(){
          $(this).parent().find('.overlay').stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 250);
        });

    $("a.view").live("mouseout", "a.view", function(){
          $(this).parent().find('.overlay').stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 250);
    });

});
```

Edit regarding your website

Try

> `<article style="display: block; z-index:1000;position:absolute;">`

It seems to display the text.

If you want to displace the next block/image, use position:absolute;

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't get it to work unfortunately. If you have time, here's a live demo of the site you can check out - http://staffanestberg.com/lesmarket/

Comment: I tried <article style="display:block; z-index:1000;position:absolute;"> and it seems to work. So it is a CSS problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your js code seems to be working fine but the only problem is that `<article>` tags get overlapped with other images shown below. You can apply this code to your `+` icon (when you hover any image) which will show the image details and push the below image down.

```
$('div#posts > div.post > a.view').each (function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var articleHeight = $(this).siblings('article').show().height();
        $('div#posts > div.post').each (function (j) {
            if (i%2 == 0 && j%2 == 0 && j > i) {
                var currentTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'));
                $(this).css({top : currentTop + articleHeight});
            } else if (i%2 != 0 && j%2 != 0 && j > i) {
                var currentTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'));
                $(this).css({top : currentTop + articleHeight});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

P.S. To see the above code working, Just run the code in console and click `+`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here's a live demo of the site. As you can see there's something preventing the text content to push down the posts below - http://staffanestberg.com/lesmarket/

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple - just add the following CSS to your article tag

```
article {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

This will place it above the other images.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the masonry reload on complete of slideUp.

```
.slideUp(400,function() {
    $('#container').masonry('reload');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bang's answer will bring you 90% of the way there.

I had this same problem too, and Bang inspired me to try the solution and it didn't quite work so I tweaked it and solved it for my use.

Here's what I did:

Yes, the 'reload' function of the masonry plugin is what you need.

Put it in the callback part of your jquery animation effect.

For me, it was:

$('#div-that-is-expanding').slideDown("slow", function(){ $('#container-for-masonry-tiles').masonry('reload'); });

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I have made a template that uses a masonry layout for a WordPress template that can be used as a blog index page, You can see its using plain CSS and you can test it out and play around with it, So far I'm using it as an alternative to having to use JQuery but Soon I will update this one to use JQuery and add cool features.

`

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <style>
        @media all and (min-width: 676px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
            #list_blog {
            -moz-column-count: 2 !important;
            -moz-column-gap: 0px !important;
            -webkit-column-count: 2 !important;
            -webkit-column-gap: 0px !important;
            column-count: 2 !important;
            column-gap: 0px !important;
            }
        }
        @media all and (max-width: 676px) {
            #list_blog {
            -moz-column-count: 1 !important;
            -webkit-column-count: 1 !important;
            column-count: 1 !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> ">
        <div class="x-container-fluid max width">
            <div id="blog_container">
            <div class="entry-content" id="list_blog"
                style=" -moz-column-count: 3;
                    -moz-column-gap: 0px;
                    -webkit-column-count: 3;
                    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
                    column-count: 3;
                    column-gap: 0px;
                ">
                <?php query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 15 ) ); ?>
                <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                <div class="post_item" style="display: inline-block;background: #fff;border-radius: 5px;box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #BBB;margin-right: 30px;width: 96%;margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <h4 class="post-heading" style="padding: 10px;margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 10px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                <div class="blog-image"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?></a></div>
                <div class="content" style="padding: 10px;"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

                </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <div class="navigation">
                    <span class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link(__('« Newer','example')) ?></span>
                    <span class="older"><?php next_posts_link(__('Older »','example')) ?></span>
                </div><!-- /.navigation -->
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div> <!-- end .entry-content -->

            </div><!--blog_container-->
        </div> <!-- .x-container-fluid.max.width -->
    </article> <!-- end .hentry -->

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>`
```